# How can I find sample mean, given n and standard deviation?

Tags: standard-deviation, means, sampling

Question is given as follow:
The pH levels of food items prepared in a certain way are normally distributed with a **standard deviation of 0.82**. An experimenter estimates the mean pH level by averaging the pH levels of a random sample of n items.

**If n = 5**, what is the probability that the experimenter’s estimate is within 0.5 of the true mean value?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:$$Pr(|\bar{X}-\mu|<0.5)$$
$$=Pr\left(\dfrac{|\bar{X}-\mu|}{\sigma /\sqrt{n}}<\dfrac{0.5}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}=1.36\right)$$
$$=Pr\left(-1.36<\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma /\sqrt{n}}<1.36\right)$$ where $Z=\dfrac{\bar{X}-\mu}{\sigma /\sqrt{n}}$ is standard normally distributed